# Is $\omega(n)=16$ the maximum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, decimal-expansion

> What is the largest possible value of $\omega(n)$ (the number of distinct prime factors of $n$) , if $n$ is a $30$-digit number containing only zeros and ones in the decimal expansion.

I checked those numbers divisible by $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17$ and the maximum value was $\omega(n)=16$ , for example for $$n=100011001000111001010100000110$$

But I did not check all those numbers , so a larger value is still possible. Is there another method than simple brute force to find such a maximum for a larger number of digits , say , $40$ ?

Bonus question : A variant is that the number must be squarefree , as the above example is. Does this make a difference or is the maximum the same , no matter how many digits we give ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using brute force I found the following numbers with $\omega(n)=16$:

```
Omega(100000100110110100000100110110) = 16, largest factor=9091
Omega(100000100111001110011001010000) = 16, largest factor=52579
Omega(100001101100110111111111011110) = 16, largest factor=67967
Omega(100001110101001100000010011010) = 16, largest factor=5927
Omega(100001111000000101101100000110) = 16, largest factor=9391
Omega(100010010001011101000000101110) = 16, largest factor=9277
Omega(100011000010011101010000101100) = 16, largest factor=61469
Omega(100011001000111001010100000110) = 16, largest factor=52579
Omega(101000111101000001000110010010) = 16, largest factor=5927
Omega(101110001111010101110001111010) = 16, largest factor=9091
Omega(110001010001100110001010001100) = 16, largest factor=9091
Omega(110011000100010110011000100010) = 16, largest factor=9091
Omega(110101111000000010000111001000) = 16, largest factor=9901
Omega(111000000010110100010111000010) = 16, largest factor=2881447
Omega(111000000101110100000110100010) = 16, largest factor=52579
Omega(111000111100000101000011000010) = 16, largest factor=9901
Omega(111010001101110101010111101010) = 16, largest factor=4723
Omega(111011100100010001000110001000) = 16, largest factor=4871
```

These are provably the only 30-digit numbers that satisfy $\omega(n)\geq 16$.

Using my brute-force algorithm (going through all binary numbers of length 30) it would be possible to extend the program to 40 digits.
But that would take about a day on a good computer that I don't have...

---

Update:
I ran the program for 35 digit numbers and found the following numbers with $\omega(n)\geq 17$ (note that there are 3 with $\omega(n)=18$, none of those are squarefree).

As a side note, these values also give all the $\omega(n)\geq 17$ values for smaller lengths of the number. Just remove $0$'s from the end.

```
Omega(10000000101100110100000101100100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10000001000100010100111010001001100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10000010001100111000010001100101000) = 18, squarefree=False
Omega(10000010101001001001000100110100010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10000111000000111000111000000101000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10000111111110011111111001111101100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001000001101100000110110000001010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10001000001101110000000110111011100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001000001101110101100100100110110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10001000111111000101110000101111010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001001010001110101001010001100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001010001011101000101110100000110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10001010110111110100101100110111010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001011011111111011011011111101010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10001011101111110111011101111100110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10001100010001010101100010001000100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001101010111111111101010111101110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001110111001100001010111011100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001111001110111111111001110101110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10001111110000000000001000100101010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10010000001011010100100100010010100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10010001001010110010001001010100000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10010010111101101101001100110011000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10010100100010100100000000101101010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10010110010011111010101101100100010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10011100000101100101111010101011010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10011100000111011011101100100001110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10011100110001011111100110001001100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10011110101111110111011101101001110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10011111001100100000110001101111010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10011111111111111111111111111101100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10100100111101001011100000001010010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10100100111101010010001101001011110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10100111111101010010001100111001000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10101000100011111111000100011101010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10101001011111111110100101111111010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10101001100110011111001100110001010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10101001100111011111010100011000100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10101010001010111100010001101111100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10101011010101001111111100111111110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10101011101110101101110100010101010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10101110011101111111110011101101010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10110000001011110101001010001101010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(10110010010111111111101111111100010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10110011001000010100101101101111010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10110011001100111011010100101101000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10110110011111100101011000100010010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10110111010101111000001110000010110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10111010111111111011010101001111010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10111011000100000101001010111101110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(10111101100101011010011111101111110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11000000000111011000001100100000110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11000000001111110001001100110100010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11000000101100001010110100000001010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11000001101100111110011001001101100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11000011011100111000000111101100110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11000100001110010000111001000000100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11000101011110111000101011000100110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11000110010100111100111101101011100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11000110101001011110110101001000110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11000111001110111011111101111100110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11001011101101111111110100111110010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11001100011111111011101100110111110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11001101100100001000000000010010110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11001110000100110001101001111110010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11001110001101011011110001101000010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11001110010001111101110010001100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11001111101110111011111101110100010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11010000000010111110000000010100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11010100000110111001011101100101010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11010100010111011110100010111000100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11010100011010000000101000000101100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11010111100011011100101000011100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11011001001111101010111110010001010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11011010100101000000011000010010000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11011010111101011111101111110100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11011011100101111110011110101000100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11011100001110110001000011111100100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11011101101110111101110110111011000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11011101110111011111101110111000100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11011101111111110010101110110110010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11011111111111100001111100101110010) = 18, squarefree=False
Omega(11100000011110000101001000010000100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11100001100011111110001100011100010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11100011011101111111101110111100010) = 18, squarefree=False
Omega(11100100101010101011000000011100010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11100111010111111110111010111100010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11101001001100010111010000111110100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11101001001100100111110010011100010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11101001001111110101011110111110110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11101011101100010011001100110100010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11101011111101011110110110001101110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11101101010110111011011101111110100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11101111111101111110011110010001100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11101111111111111111111111111100010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11110011011010111011010100011110000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11110110101001001101001000010110110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11110111101011111110111101011100000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111000001000001100000111110111110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111010110001001101101110000100010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111100001011111111111101000110110) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11111100011110111011111101000111100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111100101110111001110111001111010) = 17, squarefree=True
Omega(11111101000000111010111100000111000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111110001000100100010000000001000) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111110101100011001000110000001110) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111111010100101010110110111111010) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111111011110101100110100110111100) = 17, squarefree=False
Omega(11111111011110111011111101000100100) = 17, squarefree=False
```

These are (once again) all of the solutions.